# Core Data - Relations queries

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

In core data,

I want to use relationship. But I have a doubt in my mind. Apologies but I didn't find clear answers on various websites and blogs. Other things like Add, Fetch, Delete queries are clear to me. But I have some questions in core data which are still not clear.

I have made two Entities:

- `Photographer` [Attributes : `name` and `camera`]
- `Photo` [Attributes: `zoner` and `photographerName`] .

1) I have connected them with relations. So if I connect this two entities with relations then I should remove that `photographerName` from `Photo`?

2) As I have connected these two entities with the relation then how can I use the photographer name with the photo Entity?

3) How can I add values in this if I use it with relations? [Now it is showing me Null in the relation from sqlite browser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I connect this two entities with relations then I should remove that PhotographerName from Photo ?

Generally, yes, it is redundant.

> how can I use the photographer name with the photo Entity ?

```
self.photographer.name
```

(assuming you are in the `Photo` class and the relationship names is `photographer`)

> How can I add values in this if I use it with relations

I guess you mean how can I set the relationship value. Create an instance (or find an existing instance) or each entity and then:

```
photo.photographer = photographer;
```

Notes:

1. Ensure that the relationship has an inverse
2. Names the relationship ends `photographer` and `photos` (1 to many)
3. Try to set the `photographer` of a `photo`, or use the relationship methods auto-generated in the `Photographer` class to add photos

Comment: You need to create 2 relationships, 1 in each direction, and then set them as inverse of each other

Comment: so at both the place I need to set non inverse ? under the inverse column in relationship

Comment: when you set one as the inverse of the other both will be set as the inverse of each other

Comment: and I found this relationship object in photo class .. @property (nonatomic, retain) Photographer *relationshipInv; .. so using relationshipInv.name I can set the photographer name for particular image .. right ?

Comment: yes, but name your relationships more obviously like I suggest in the answer and you wouldn't usually set the photographer name from the photo (bit weird)

Comment: in every photo .. I want to relate a name of photographer .. so I should write a name of photographer in the photo class .. am I doing it right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48813/discussion-between-wain-and-jean-luc-godard)